# How to paint a 2D surface

Tags: texture-painting

I have a model which I want to modify the paint on part of it (see image below with area circled in red where I want to repaint part of the area using the same 'color' - current it has two 'colors' black and nearly white).
I am using v3.2 and opted to try to use the CLONE tool which doesn't seem to work with the 3d imager.
I have watched a Youtube video and assume that the author is using some other version as (using the 2D imager) he mentions that he selects Brush Settings and then Advanced and then he can select an image. I do not see that option (image).

If I want to simply remove MOST but not all the dark 'stripes' and replace them with the adjacent 'color' what is the method?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: To paint just the selected mesh faces, I'd use the Face Select Masking in the 3d view texture paint mode to isolate the paint to only where you are wanting. There isn't an easy way to do that in the 2d image editor at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I will try that when I get back from a trip I start today. I noted from the tutorial I watched that painting using 2d image editor isn't easy however I still could not get to work what I saw. I am assuming that I need to use the 2d image editor as I could not get to work what I saw being done with the 3d image editor - my model is of an aircraft which I assumed would be a 3d image, can you tell from the image I posted? Thanks again.